# JSFiddle basic form validation with regex not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/gzLeLjmb/

For some reason JSFiddle is throwing an error and I can't work out why? I'm just trying to validate an input with a regex for a persons name.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  function validateForm() {
    var userName = $("input[name=userName]").val();
    var subject = $("input[name=subject]").val();
    var message = $("input[name=message]").val();

    if (/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/.test(userName)) {
      alert("Your name is in the correct format");
    } else {
      alert("Your name can't contain numbers or other characters etc.");
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: The closing curly brace of the `ready`'s argument is missing.

Comment: you should specify the error more clearly as it could be as @teemu stated, you're missing a ) which it quiet clearly states in the console. Or it could be that you have jsfiddle set to run javascript onLoad instead of in body. It could also be something completely different, Please give more information regarding your error

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine to me, except that you should use **return false** to prevent form from submitting formData.

Also separating javascript logic from the html is recommended.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('form').on('submit', function() {
        var userName = $("input[name=userName]").val();
        var subject = $("input[name=subject]").val();
        var message = $("input[name=message]").val();
        if (/^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/.test(userName)) {
             alert("Your name is in the correct format");
        }
        else{
            alert("Your name can't contain numbers or other characters etc.");
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```